# Como mudar a tela de loading do Ionic 3

Tags: cordova-plugin, ionic3

Como alterar a tela de *loading* padrão do Ionic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa editar as imagens `icon.png` e `splash.png` do diretório `resources`, conforme documentação: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/resources/

Depois de editar as imagens, execute: `ionic cordova resources [<platform>]` que as imagens de icon e splash serão atualizadas.